# Is book value in BVPS really just shareholders equity?

Tags: stocks, financial-literacy, stock-analysis, terminology, stock-valuation

So shareholders equity is ***total* assets - total liabilities** while book value is ***tangible* assets - total liabilities**. But apparently book value in practice could also just be **total assets - total liabilities**  (here intangible assets are also included). Is this the case in the BVPS formula - **(total shareholder's equity - preferred equity) / total outstanding shares**) - since the formula just specifies total shareholders equity and not book value? The reason I'm confused is cause of the name (of BVPS) which I assumed implies we use the strict definition of book value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Shareholder equity = Book value (tangible+intangible)

Shareholder's equity is the remaining assets available to investors once all liabilities have been paid.

It's calculated as:

```
Book Value = Shareholder Equity = Total Assets – Total Liabilities
```

And thus:

```
BVPS = (Total Assets – Total Liabilities)/(shr outstanding)
```

---

#### Book value (tangible)

Book value (tangible) is:

```
Book Value (tangible) = Total Assets – Intangible Assets – Total Liabilities
                      = Tangible Assets – Total Liabilities
```

Following,

```
Tangible BVPS = (Tangible Assets – Total Liabilities)/(shr outstanding)
```

> But apparently book value in practice could also just be total assets - total liabilities

That is the definition of "book value", but isn't "tangible book value", unless Intangible Assets = 0.

> (here intangible assets are also included)

They shouldn't be for Book value (tangible).

---

#### Answer question

> The reason I'm confused is cause of the name (of BVPS) which I assumed implies we use the strict definition of book value.

You're confused because there are actually two different BVPS variants:

1. BVPS
2. Tangible BVPS

It's even on Seeking Alpha in the Supplemental Items section of stocks' balance sheet:

[image]

---

addendum: usually, BVPS (rather than intangible BVPS) is used to compute P/B.